# How can i choose a particular sheet and display the data in it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, excel

How can I choose a particular sheet and display the data in it. I have used some of the functions in the code which library functions should I add to execute the code?

It is displaying all the Excel file data, but I want specific page or sheet to be displayed.

```
<?php

require 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

// Mysql database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123456";
$dbname = "import_db";

$inputfilename = $_POST['fileToUpload'];
$exceldata = array();

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//  Read your Excel workbook
try
{
    $inputfiletype = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputfilename);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputfiletype);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputfilename);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputfilename,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}

//  Get worksheet dimensions
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
//$sheetNames = $sheet->getSheetNames(); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
 $count=$objPHPExcel->getSheetCount();
 $names = $objPHPExcel->getSheetNames();
 echo $count;
echo $names;
//echo $sheetNames;
//  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
{ 
    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

    $exceldata[] = $rowData[0];

}

// Print excel data
 echo "<table>";
foreach ($exceldata as $index => $excelraw)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($excelraw as $excelcolumn)
    {
        echo "<td>".$excelcolumn."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>"; 

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change below code in **try** and it will work for you.

```
try 
{
   $sheetname = 'Data Sheet #2';  // Sheet name which you want to load    
   $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputfiletype); // Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputfiletype

   $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname); // Advise the Reader of which WorkSheets we want to load

   $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputfilename); //Load $inputfilenameto a PHPExcel Object  
 }
```